# squid proxy refuse connection on telegram and twitter

Tags: linux, proxy, centos, squid

Os : `centos 7`
I made a proxy server base on [squid on centos](https://www.tecmint.com/install-squid-http-proxy-on-centos-7/) and it works on much websites , but not on telegram or twitter .
this is my `squid.conf`

```
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 2083     # cpanel manager
acl SSL_ports  port 2096        # cpanel webmail
acl SSL_ports  port 8443        # cpanel webmail
acl SSL_ports  port 80      # cpanel webmail

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

http_access deny !Safe_ports

http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost

http_access allow all

http_port 3128

coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320
```

> when open the telegram its stay on `connectiong...` and the twitter , its says `proxy refused the connection`

[image]
[image]

I disabled `http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports` in `squid.conf` but it didn't work either.